# Insert two horizontal lines above and below Contents and List of Figures

Tags: formatting

[image]

I would like to know how to insert horizontal lines above and below the Contents and the List of Figures. I managed to do it for the title of the chapters but not for the TOC and List of Figures. For the chapters I used the following code:

```
\usepackage{titles}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\huge}
  {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}

  {3ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}

  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

Comment: Where does package `titles` come from?  Can you please complete your code snippet to be compilable? Which document class do you use?  If not a standard one please provide a link for the document class ...

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to you preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  {\bfseries\huge}
  {}
  {0ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

All unnumbered chapter titles, including the table of ontents, the list of figures, &c.  will be left aligned and ruled.

Comment: Although I have a personal dislike for `titlesec` most likely a simpler solution than what I would have provided. (+1)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I'm curious of why this loathing?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't work. I guess it has something to do with the document class scrbook. I attach a short version of the code that I use.

Comment: \documentclass
  [paper=a4,  
  twoside=on,  
 DIV=13,   
        fontsize=11pt, 
 BCOR=15.0mm, 
 parskip=half, 
 cleardoublepage=empty] 
 {scrbook} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}
    {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
    {3ex}
    {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
    [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

Comment: \begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
some text here
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\chapter{Introduction}
some text here
\end{document}